# Having multiple optional segments in a NancyFX Route

Tags: nancy

I have the following route in NancyFX:

```
Get["/Foo/{A?}/{B?}/{C?}"] = request => {  /* some stuff */ };
```

It responds to `http://localhost:1234/Foo/` amd `http://localhost:1234/Foo//1/2/3/` but not `http://localhost:1234/Foo/1/` and `http://localhost:1234/Foo/1/2/`. Basically you have to include all or none of the optional segments.I know I could use multiple segments, but how can I make each segment individually optional, and only dependent on the preceding segments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Get["/Foo/{A?}"] = 
Get["/Foo/{A?}/{B?}"] = 
Get["/Foo/{A?}/{B?}/{C?}"] = request => {  /* some stuff */ };
```

Comment: That's a creative use of syntax.

Comment: I don't know any other way of doing this.

Comment: Awesome! this saved me a whole bunch of keystrokes today :-)